# NLog configuration - log into xml - Passing Custom Values to Log4JXmlEventLayout

Tags: .net, nlog

I am trying to write the log into xml file using NLog 2.0. in .net framework 3.5.

Here is the layout I am using.

layout="${log4jxmlevent:includelongdate=true:includeexception=true:includeSourceInfo=true:includeCallSite=true:appInfo=true:includeNLogData=true:includestacktrace=true:throwExceptions=true:includeerror=true:indentXml=true:includeNLogData=true}" >

But this doesn't give me the right module or class name or logger as in the data base configuration layout="${logger:shortName=true}".

Is there anyway to get more info on the module/class/logger name in xml config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve my problem by using the NLog.MappedDiagnosticsContext

NLog.MappedDiagnosticsContext.Set("Program", ex.Source);
NLog.MappedDiagnosticsContext.Set("Alert", "High");